# Read localStorage from InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, variables, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

In the app I'm writing there are two scenarios:

1. some pages in which a user fills-in some form with various information (various pages)
2. an inAppBrowser instance that displays a webpage on the Internet, not a local page

In "scenario 1" the input data are stored in localStorage with "localStorage.setItem",

an example is:

```
    var keywords = document.getElementById("keywords").value;

    localStorage.setItem("keywords", keywords);
```

I can correctly get and display the value from within the app, in every single page with

```
    var keyWord = localStorage.getItem( 'keywords' );

    alert( keyWord );
```

What i'd like to achieve is to be able to read the values from localStorage and use it in "scenario 2".

Explain: i'd like to be able to access and read the collected "keywords" from the inAppBrowser instance, inside executeScript, to pass some variables.

Is it possible? Any idea?

Thanks,

Mimmo

I've already tried with postmessage but it looks to work the opposite way (inAppBrowser -> app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use executeScript :

```
let test ;
test.executeScript(
{
code: "let keywords = document.getElementById('keywords').value;

localStorage.setItem('keywords', keywords);"

}, function()
{
let k = localStorage.getItem( 'keywords' );

alert( k );
});
```

if the method below is not working, try to use this :

in inappbrowser:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
console.log('parent received message!:  ',e.data);
```

And in index.html of cordova :

```
parent.postMessage("test message","*");
```

Comment: Thank you Melvita but I'm afraid that unfortunately this solution cannot be applied to my setup..the input form and the inAppBrowser instance are on two different pages and only the second page ( the one with inAppBrowser ) have "executeScript".
To be more precise, what I need is pass some values from a parent webview ( the app ) and a child ( the app part with inAppBrowser ). Hop this can help to better understand the situation.